# ArrayCollection. Passed variable is not an array or object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have run the command `composer update` and after that I get error:

> InvalidArgumentException:
>     Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead

\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:277

```php
public function getIterator()
{
    return new ArrayIterator($this->elements);
}
```

Old method looks like this:

```php
public function getIterator()
{
    return new ArrayIterator($this->_elements);
}
```

I tried to dump object:

```php
var_dump($this);

/*
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[1621]
  private 'elements' => null
  private '_elements' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'upload_d986a3d2395d68bf64191583da658692d895379b.png' (length=66)
      1 => string 'upload_855c4b484dfbf4bc5e77c5dbea187cf4740efba8.png' (length=66)
*/

var_dump($this->elements);

/*
null
*/
```

Old working versions:

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.3
doctrine/cache                       v1.3.1
doctrine/collections                 v1.2
doctrine/common                      v2.4.2
doctrine/data-fixtures               v1.0.0
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.1
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             v1.3.0
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       v1.0.1
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle    v2.2.0
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1
doctrine/orm                         v2.4.7
```

New versions:

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.7
doctrine/cache                       v1.5.1
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0
doctrine/common                      v2.5.1
doctrine/data-fixtures               v1.1.1
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.2
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.0
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.2.2
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle    v2.2.1
doctrine/inflector                   v1.1.0
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.5
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

`private 'elements' => null` is not an array or an object. So that would explain the error. Maybe try to pass the whole object instead.